# How to implement paging for asp:DataList in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0, paging, datalist

I spent hours researching the problem, and just want to share a solution in case you ever need to implement paging for asp:DataList in .NET 2.0.

**My specific requirement was to have "Previous" and "Next" links and page number links.**

Comment: It is better to ask the question in your post and then respond separately with "your answer." This way folks are not led into believing (from just reading your thread title) that you're still waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved this from the question, so it doesn't appear as "Not Answered"...

[PagedDataSource solution in this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20180402032034/http://aspdotnetcodes.com:80/DataList_Dynamic_Paging_PagedDataSource.aspx) was the most elegant and simple solution for this problem.

If you have a better solution - post it here please.

**p.s. I'm not affiliated with that website in any way.**